# ClickOnce Manifest Application in TFS build

Tags: c#, clickonce, manifest, code-signing, tfsbuild

Does anyone know how to use code signing certificate for ClickOnce manifest applications in TFS Hosted Controller Build?

**Scenario:**

I am using Team Foundation Service as a code repository and source control. I have created a build definition using team explorer (Visual Studio 2012).

Build "***Process***" using Default Template configured to **Any CPU|Release**

The build is set to "**Manual *trigger***" uses **Hosted Build Controller**.

TFS build is unsuccessful if my project use Code Signing and Code manifests.

In my solution, two projects having "ClickOnce manifests"

Local build dont have any issues with Code signing and ClickOnce manifests - because Code signing certificate available locally for the build.

But for the same build in TFS, i get the error "**Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store.**"
(just one error blocking the build)

**Question**

How can I install the code signing certificate into "TFS Build Service Account" or "Build service user account"?

How can I make the code signing certificate to avail in the virtual build machine's certificate store?

Any alternative to get clean TFS build with Code signing and ClickOnce Manifests?

Have not find the solution yet :( anyone helpful here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have managed to Sign my ClickOnce manifest in TFS auto build. My certificate was password protected and build server was not able to access the certificate because of that reason. The certificate was not in my personal certificate store hence I had the trouble.

I have imported the certificate into my local machine's personal store and from there i have referenced it for signing the clickonce manifest. When you reference the certificate from the personal store, it will not ask for the password. Hence you can cheat the TFS build and that can now access your code signing certificate..

Comment: So is it as simple as just importing it into the personal certificate store and that's it? I've done that on the build server and I still get the same error.

Answer (score -2):

I have a possible alternative to get a clean build for you.

My company produces a product called ClickOnceMore ([www.clickoncemore.net](http://www.clickoncemore.net)) which can be used to build your ClickOnce manifests rather than MSBuild. It's designed to be easily integrated into a continuous integration build using a command line interface.

To integrate into your build:
* Turn off clickonce in your visual studio solution
* Create a ClickOnceMore project
* To sign the manifests you just need to put the signing certificate in a known folder location and then reference it from the ClickOnceMore project
* Add a new build step in TFS to build the ClickOnceMore project

Hope that helps.